# Sum of a column not working php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the sum of a whole  column but it's not working.

What should i change in my code .

```
//error -> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
<?php
include("connect2.php");

$value = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(total) AS sum_total * FROM `posts` ") ;

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($value);

$sum_total = $row['sum_total'];
?>
<div>
<a>
<?php echo  $sum_total; ?>
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: `AS sum_total *` what is `*` for?

Comment: what's the **** doing ?

Comment: Take the * out of the query. Also be aware that mysql_* functions are removed in PHP7 and deprecated in previous versions. It would be a good idea to switch to [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)  or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try without the `*`:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS sum_total FROM `posts`
```